# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:

Tags: php, laravel

Hello please i am a new user of larvel, i have such error while trying to create a link to register, it throws the error above

my controller is

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('register', [
        'as' => 'get_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth/RegisterController@RegistersUsers'
        ]);

    Route::post('register', [
        'as' => 'post_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth/RegisterController@register'
        ]);
});
```

and my links is

```
 <a href="{{ url('register') }}">Register</a>
```

i have created a register.blade.php inside auth folder in view. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You prefixed your urls by `auth`. In your link, try to use this syntax :

```
<a href="{{ url('auth/register') }}">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like

```
<a href="{{ route('name-of-route') }}">Register</a>
```

In Your case

```
<a href="{{ route('get_register') }}">Register</a>
```

Comment: Yes i have trried that, its not working, still getting Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:

Comment: Do you have 'Auth' directory in controller ??

Comment: Yes there is Auth directory in controller with ForgotPasswordController.php, LoginController.php, RegisterController.php and ResetPasswordController.php

Comment: if you are trying to use | edit Auth's RegisterController.php check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-register-a-user-in-laravel-53

Answer (score 1):

I think your code need to update like:

Your *controller/route*

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function(){

     Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@RegistersUsers')->name('get_register');

     Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('post_register');

});
```

and your links is:

`<a href="{{ route('get_register') }}">Register</a>`

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Thanks bro, but its not working, please note that im using laravel 5.4 and my route is inside routes folder/web.php